# Elixir: Write to a file and create parent directories if they don't exist - in one line

Tags: file-io, elixir

Is there a function in Elixir to:

- write contents to a given file path (or alternatively, create the file)
- create the parent directory is if it does not exist

Currently, I have written a function like this, although it is rather
inconvenient to write this for every project where I want to write to a file
whose parents may not exist yet.

```ex
defp write_to_file(path, contents) do
  with :ok <- File.mkdir_p(Path.dirname(path)),
       :ok <- File.write(path, contents)
  do
    :ok
  end
end
```

The most ideal situation is for something like this to exist as part of the Elixir standard library, however I cannot find something like this

```ex
File.write(path, content, create_parents: true)
```

Comment: I was looking for the same thing a while ago, but I think we are stuck creating the directory first.

Comment: You would get the same result with `with :ok <- File.mkdir_p(Path.dirname(path)), do: File.write(path, contents)`. It's still not pretty, but it's on one line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing like that in the [standard library](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html). Though why not just do this:

```ex
File.mkdir_p!(Path.dirname(path))
File.write(path, contents)
```

---

But if you want to pass on errors from `mkdir`, you can simplify your code a bit like this:

```ex
with :ok <- File.mkdir_p(Path.dirname(path)) do
  File.write(path, contents)
end
```

Comment: I think `File.mkdir_p!(File.dirname(path))` should be `File.mkdir_p!(Path.dirname(path))`

Comment: Ah my bad. Fixed.